Modifying query during maintenance window on specific date and time
| tstats count where index=cts-dcpsa-app sourcetype=app:dcpsa host_ip IN (xx.xx.xxx.xxx, xx.xx.xxx.xxx, xx.xx.xxx.xxx) by host 
| eval current_time=_time
| eval excluded_start_time=strptime("2024-04-14 21:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
| eval excluded_end_time=strptime("2024-04-15 04:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
| eval is_maintenance_window=if(current_time >= excluded_start_time AND current_time < excluded_end_time, 1, 0)
| eval is_server_down=if((host="xx.xx.xxx.xxx" AND count == 0) OR (host="xx.xx.xxx.xxx" AND count == 0) OR (host="xx.xx.xxx.xxx" AND COUNT == 0), 1, 0)

Above is my query with Trigger condition- |search  is_maintenance window = 0 AND is_server_down=1
Problem is alert should not be triggered from 9 pm to 4 am on specific date even when server goes down. Alert should only be triggers outside maintenance window when one of server goes down
I tried the above query but I am not getting results outside maintenance window even though the server is down`

I usually get better results by putting the trigger condition in the search itself and having the alert trigger when the number of results is not zero.
| tstats count where index=cts-dcpsa-app sourcetype=app:dcpsa host_ip IN (xx.xx.xxx.xxx, xx.xx.xxx.xxx) by host
| eval current_time=_time
| eval excluded_start_time=strptime("2024-04-14 21:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
| eval excluded_end_time=strptime("2024-04-15 04:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
| eval is_maintenance_window=if(current_time >= excluded_start_time AND current_time < excluded_end_time, 1, 0)
| eval is_server_down=if(count == 0, 1, 0) 
| where is_maintenance window = 0 AND is_server_down=1


by changing trigger condition number of results not equal to zero its triggering false alert meaning servers are up but alerts are getting triggered

The only results that should appear are those where the server is down and not in maintenance.  Can you share the output?

Trigger Time: 11:41:36 -0400 on April 15, 2024.
View results in Splunk
host count is_maintenance_window is_server_down
xx.xx.xxx.xxx 1571 0 0
xx.xx.xxx.xxx 1448 0 0
_
